# Hibernate : One to many Mapping between Join Table and Table C

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am having a situation as Below.

```
class Group{
  @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "group_question",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "group_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "question_id") }
    )
    private List<VisaQuestionMetaEntity> question;

}
Class Question {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "question")
    private List<QuestionnaireGroupEntity> group;

}

Class Options {
     // Relation will be one to many relation between GROUP_QUESTION and Answers
}
```

So There is Many to Many mapping between Group and Questions. But One to many mapping between `Group_Question` and Options. 
So I am able to `create a Join` table between Group and Questions having `group_id` and `enter code here`question_id with current Entities. 
I am stuck on how to specify `group_id` and `question_id` as a composite key to the Options entity.

Comment: As far as I know, you can not reference non-entities so Group_Question can't be added to options. I have a suggestion though, how about you creat the Group_Question yourself as an entity and include group and question inside of it. then add this Group_Question entity to Options? I am not sure if i am 100% correct and would love to know if there is another way.

Comment: Suggestion looks fair and resonable. Although now, The relationship in the question doesn't exist any more and I had to redesign the tables. But still I will like to know if there are any Solutions.